# Commands are not working even when I tried to give permissions

Tags: magento2, command-line, ssh

I am trying to run commands through ssh, but commands are not working. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: what is your project folder path ?

Comment: web/shops/htdocs . i am currently in my project folder

Comment: check this, it would be php path issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009623/php-command-not-found/43009817

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: have you installed PHP? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means the **php** not set as a Environment Variable.

So it must be tried with a full path with php:

```
/opt/lammp/bin/php
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt)

Comment: no such file or directory found ... http://prntscr.com/ky5ct1

Comment: @samairali it is example not the correct path you have to find yours.

Comment: What do you mean by "global variable"? Isn't this about search paths?

Comment: @PeterMortensen  my mistake it is a Environment variable. added the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Run this in SSH:

`which php`

And then provide the full path e.g.:

`/usr/bin/php bin/magento`

*Replace the `/usr/bin/php` with the result of `which php` command*

Comment: This won't help.  `which` just searches the path ... if `php` can be found on the path, then running it without the full path would work just fine.

Comment: I had a same problem, and specifying the full path to the php worked. Like in the answer by @PROGOSTECH setting a php global variable solved the problem permanently.